# install gem http_parser on windows

Tags: ruby, makefile, rubygems, bootstrap-4

I dealing with project Symfony and Bootstrap 4 I would like to work with source bootstrap. For that I need ruby and all bundle.

**I launch this command** : `bundler install` and I have error install on http_parser.rb (0.6.0)

**I launch this command** : `gem install http_parser.rb --source 'http://rubygems.org/' --install-dir '/dev/tmp/http'`

but I have this error : `C:/dev/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/make-0.3.1/bin/make:4:in`': undefined local variable or method `make' for main:Object (NameError)
        from C:/dev/Ruby24-x64/bin/make:22:in`load'
        from C:/dev/Ruby24-x64/bin/make:22:in `<main>'`

**So I installed make tools with** : `gem install make
Successfully installed make-0.3.1
Parsing documentation for make-0.3.1
Done installing documentation for make after 0 seconds
1 gem installed`

**And I retry to install http_parser with** : `gem install http_parser.rb --source 'http://rubygems.org/' --install-dir '/dev/tmp/http'`

But nothing change. I again this error : `` C:/dev/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/make-0.3.1/bin/make:4:in `<top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `make' for main:Object (NameError)
        from C:/dev/Ruby24-x64/bin/make:22:in `load'
        from C:/dev/Ruby24-x64/bin/make:22:in `<main>' ``

How install http_parser gem on windows OS ?

Why make don't run correctly but install correct ?

Comment: Did you install Ruby with the DevKit bundle? If not then reinstall and try again.

Comment: To add on to @Casper's comment here is a link with instructions for installing the DevKit: https://rubyinstaller.org/add-ons/devkit.html

Comment: Installed latest version of Ruby devKit 2.5 solved my issue. Warning Ruby devKit 2.4 don't run. @Casper post reply solution and I check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that Ruby needs to compile native (non-Ruby) code in order to install and use the http_parser gem.

To compile native code on Windows you need to install Ruby with the DevKit package. If you use RubyInstaller you just choose the **Ruby+DevKit** package instead of the plain Ruby package. This should allow the http_parser installation to complete.

Comment: WARNING : very careful about version of your Ruby DevKit. Thank you for response @Casper